# Kubernetes Upgrade - 1.17.8 to 1.18.20 fails at first master node (IPv6 only cluster)

Tags: kubernetes

Would need some help with debugging the upgrade failure.

Upgrade failure of Ipv6 cluster (3 master nodes) from 1.17.8 to 1.18.20.

Error Traces

---

```
/usr/bin/kubeadm upgrade apply v1.18.20 -y
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Running cluster health checks
[upgrade/version] You have chosen to change the cluster version to "v1.18.20"
[upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.17.8
[upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.18.20
[upgrade/prepull] Will prepull images for components [kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler etcd]
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulling image for component etcd.
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulling image for component kube-scheduler.
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulling image for component kube-controller-manager.
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulling image for component kube-apiserver.
[apiclient] Found 3 Pods for label selector k8s-app=upgrade-prepull-kube-apiserver
[apiclient] Found 0 Pods for label selector k8s-app=upgrade-prepull-kube-scheduler
[apiclient] Found 3 Pods for label selector k8s-app=upgrade-prepull-kube-controller-manager
[apiclient] Found 0 Pods for label selector k8s-app=upgrade-prepull-etcd
[apiclient] Found 3 Pods for label selector k8s-app=upgrade-prepull-etcd
[apiclient] Found 3 Pods for label selector k8s-app=upgrade-prepull-kube-scheduler
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulled image for component kube-apiserver.
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulled image for component kube-scheduler.
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulled image for component kube-controller-manager.
[upgrade/prepull] Prepulled image for component etcd.
[upgrade/prepull] Successfully prepulled the images for all the control plane components
[upgrade/apply] Upgrading your Static Pod-hosted control plane to version "v1.18.20"...
Static pod: kube-apiserver-cvmonq1 hash: 1c8ea0abd77378cdddfef939bb4154ad
Static pod: kube-controller-manager-cvmonq1 hash: 00363dd5e255940e1cc72f797b04b39f
Static pod: kube-scheduler-cvmonq1 hash: 7d3db474476c65a94558519f47794665
[upgrade/etcd] Upgrading to TLS for etcd
[upgrade/etcd] Non fatal issue encountered during upgrade: the desired etcd version for this Kubernetes version "v1.18.20" is "3.4.3-0", but the current etcd version is "3.4.3". Won't downgrade etcd, instead just continue
[upgrade/staticpods] Writing new Static Pod manifests to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-upgraded-manifests431381277"
W0418 20:45:26.227640 1725518 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
[upgrade/staticpods] Preparing for "kube-apiserver" upgrade
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing apiserver certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing front-proxy-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Renewing apiserver-etcd-client certificate
[upgrade/staticpods] Moved new manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml" and backed up old manifest to "/etc/kubernetes/tmp/kubeadm-backup-manifests-2022-04-18-20-45-24/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[upgrade/staticpods] Waiting for the kubelet to restart the component
[upgrade/staticpods] This might take a minute or longer depending on the component/version gap (timeout 5m0s)
Static pod: kube-apiserver-cvmonq1 hash: 1c8ea0abd77378cdddfef939bb4154ad


[upgrade/apply] FATAL: couldn't upgrade control plane. kubeadm has tried to recover everything into the earlier state. Errors faced: timed out waiting for the condition
```

On adding verbose level debug, timeout seen at

```
I0418 20:56:37.525538 1734292 round_trippers.go:444] GET https://[2001:420:293:2471:172:29:54:135]:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-apiserver-cvmonq1?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0418 20:56:37.525572 1734292 round_trippers.go:450] Response Headers:
I0418 20:56:37.525817 1734292 round_trippers.go:424] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.18.20 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/1f3e19b" 'https://[2001:420:293:2471:172:29:54:135]:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-apiserver-cvmonq1?timeout=10s'
I0418 20:56:37.526212 1734292 round_trippers.go:444] GET https://[2001:420:293:2471:172:29:54:135]:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-apiserver-cvmonq1?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0418 20:56:37.526237 1734292 round_trippers.go:450] Response Headers:
timed out waiting for the condition
couldn't upgrade control plane. kubeadm has tried to recover everything into the earlier state. Errors faced
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade.rollbackOldManifests
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade/staticpods.go:520
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade.upgradeComponent
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade/staticpods.go:252
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade.StaticPodControlPlane
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade/staticpods.go:477
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade.PerformStaticPodUpgrade
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/upgrade/staticpods.go:611
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.PerformControlPlaneUpgrade
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/apply.go:223
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.runApply
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/apply.go:164
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.NewCmdApply.func1
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/apply.go:79
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
[upgrade/apply] FATAL
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.runApply
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/apply.go:165
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.NewCmdApply.func1
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/apply.go:79
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
[root@cvmonq1 manifests]#
```

Boostrapping of IPV6 direcly in v.1.18.20 works in the same setup without any issues.

Failure observed only in the update path.
Any inputs to debug/fix the issue is appreciated.

Comment: Try draining the control plane node first **kubectl drain <cp-node-name> --ignore-daemonsets** and then run **kubeadm upgrade**.Have a look at this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/) .Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Fariya Yes, followed the same steps outlined in the document. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are hitting is because  you are trying to upgrade from the current version to the current version.

Checkout the [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65071) link for more information.

Another workaround can be to downgrade your cluster version and then upgrade as mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1054).